# How to animate a single imageview in listview in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a custom listview that has imageviews in every listview item. I try to apply alpha animation at single imageview after it’s been loaded but the animation applys on all imageviwes in the same listview which making the ones that already loaded blinks again and again.

I animate imageviews inside getView method inside my base adapter class:

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View v = arg1;
        if(arg1 == null){
            v = infalter.inflate(R.layout.home_main_list_view_row, null);
        }
        ImageView cover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.homeCoverImageView);
            AlphaAnimation alpha = (AlphaAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
            cover.startAnimation(alpha);
        return v;
    }
```

I looked up everywhere but I haven’t get to what I want.

**Edit**

AsyncTask:

```
    class downloadImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String link = null;
    int index = 0;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int x = covers.size(); x < covers_links.size(); x++){
            index = x;
            link = covers_links.get(x).trim();
            if(downloadImages.isCancelled()){
                break;
            }else if(link.matches("")){
                covers.add(null);
            }else{              
                BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(link).openStream(), null, bfo);
                    int scale = calculateInSampleSize(bfo, 275, 300);
                    bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bfo.inSampleSize = scale;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(link).openStream(), null, bfo);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                covers.add(x, bitmap);
            }
            publishProgress();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Bitmap loader:

```
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, i think what you are doing is a bit messy, but if you want to continue that way you can get the specific ImageView of the child in the listview with this method:

```
ImageView cover = (ImageView) mListView.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.homeCoverImageView);
```

Then you can apply the animation the the cover with ObjectAnimator you i have shown in my old answer..

If i were supposed to do this i would simply use the [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/#download) in the `getView()` method in your adapter.. You can reduce all that code to just one line, it loads the image from the url, resize it, and fade it in (In just one single statement!!)

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .resize(50, 50)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(cover)
```

When the Image is loaded it will automatically fade it into the `cover` ImageView.. Don't try to reinvent the wheel my friend.

## **Old Answer**

You need to set the position of the imageView you want to animate.. When your `getView` method get called for each item, the animation is called for each view.

Try do something like this (for the imageview position 1)

In the `getView`

```
...

ImageView cover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.homeCoverImageView);

if(arg0 == 1){
    ObjectAnimator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cover, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fade.setDuration(400);
    fade.start();
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your contributing but I don’t see that you specify any positions in your snippet. It checks position 1 but applies animation on all imageviews. This is the same problem that I’m facing.

Comment: Have you tried this code? I have tested it and it works.. It can not apply the animation to all imageviews, only the one in the pos == 1 (the arg0 variable is the position!!), the rest will not be animated, because the ObjectAnimator doesn't get called when the position is not 1! Try set the duration to 5000, and you can see the difference

Comment: But what if I want to apply alpha animation at all imageviews sequently but when image has loaded?

Comment: Are you loading images from the internet?? In that case which library do you use?

Comment: Yes, I’m. I use this method: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`

Comment: Ahh i see. Well as far as i can see the BitmapFactory doesnt have a listener that is called when the image is loaded, so it will be hard to know when the Image is loaded and the animation can start.. Instead i suggest to use [this library](https://github.com/square/picasso), It is very easy, and it have a automatic function build in that fade's the images when they are loaded. If you want i can write a sample of how to use it.

Comment: I have checked it long time ago but I prefer to use Android API with options to reduce image size. I have a void method that loops at all images and execute AsyncTask for every image. So I know when image will be ready to setting as a bitmap but I have no idea how to retrieve that row from listview and find image by id. It would be very helpful if you could write a code explain this.

Comment: Try show the code for the AsyncTask and the Bitmap loader

Comment: I edited my code. In fact it is one AsyncTask that loops images links in `doInBackground` and calls `onProgressUpdate` everytime a new bitmap is loaded.